# Sample/default values.yaml file for Zookeeper (v3.5 or v3.6) on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, helm3

I am looking for a sample/default values.yaml file for Zookeeper (v3.5 or v3.6) on Kubernetes.  I am hoping the values.yaml file will have config for statefulset, deployment, env, etc.

Can someone suggest some credible site or method.

Thank you,
Ahmed.

Comment: which helm chart you are using? it's totally dependent on the helm chart

Comment: I am using helm3, not sure if that is what you were asking. I am looking for a sample one I can use to deploy a basic zookeeper cluster in a kubernetes cluster.